# PHPMyAdmin Syntax Error wpDataTables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

This MySQL looks fine when I run it in workbench, but throws an error when running through phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT 
   round(AVG(compoundScore),3) as 'Sentiment Score',
   count(*) as 'Tweets',
   (DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"),
   INTERVAL (case when MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) < 30 then 0 else 1 end) HOUR)) AS the_rounded_date
FROM rawTweets
WHERE
   date = CURDATE()
   AND LOCATE('trump', cleanTweet)
   AND compoundScore IS NOT NULL
   AND compoundScore != 0.0
GROUP BY the_rounded_date


MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; 30 then 0 else 1 end) HOUR)) AS the_rounded_date FROM rawTweets WHERE date = C' at line 1.
```

Comment: You're probably copying and pasting it from a web browser so your `<` becomes `&lt;`. Using the mysql console is a good way to avoid these problems.

Comment: The same query works in MySQL Workbench but gives this error in phpMyAdmin? That's quite interesting as this error message comes from MySQL, not phpMyAdmin. Could you provide your table structure and a row or two of sample data on the phpMyAdmin bug tracker at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/ ?